# terms aggregation with aggregation filter returns more doc_count than without aggregation filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I store some data as nested object in ElasticSearch but the aggregation results don't make sense to me. Don't know why when applying aggregation filter, I will have more nested objects in doc_count.

```
|                        | terms w.o. | terms with |
|                        | agg filter | agg filter |
|------------------------|-----------:|-----------:|
| total documents        | 41,690,696 | 41,690,696 |
| nested object          | 77,999,324 | 77,999,324 |
| filtered nested object | 77,999,324 |     89,116 |
| agg "ITEM 1"           |     87,905 |     89,116 |
| reversed agg           |     19,976 |     20,499 |
```

Query payload for `with aggregation filter` is shown below and remove the must part will become `without aggregation filter` query.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "requestedDimension": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "NESTED_PATH"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "requestedDimension": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [   // query for without filter will remove this must
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "NESTED_PATH.PROP": [
                      "ITEM_1"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "disable_coord": false,
              "adjust_pure_negative": true
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "requestedDimension": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "NESTED_PATH.PROP1",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "userCount": {
                  "reverse_nested": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would you please try with size:0 in terms aggregation and share the results?

Comment: hum... does your field NESTED_PATH.PROP1 has multiple words and maybe is not analyzed?  
the only way I think this could happen is if your field has big texts (multiple phrases) that are being analyzed/tokenized and then when you apply the filter(possibly with multiple words as well) it matches more entries than without it. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is because Terms aggregation is approximate
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts

That `PROP` is a high cardinality property, therefore the overall top 10 elements may not be top 10 elements in each shard. When I apply filter aggregation, it filter out all elements other than top 10 elements, therefore it makes sure all top 10 elements are counted.